# Can't get rid of vertical scroll-bar that holds thumbnails in photo gallery

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, picasa, photo-gallery

I used Picasa to create an image gallery, which is part of a website that I am creating.

I can't figure out how to remove the scroll-bar (it holds thumbnails) on the side that I think is from an iframe? Here are the pages that I have to work with:

The "imageset.html" code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Forest Village</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<frameset cols="180,*" border="0">
<frame src="thumbnails.html" scrolling="yes" border="0">
</frame>
<frame src="target0.html" name="images" border="0">
</frame>
</frameset>
</frame>
</frameset>
```

I think that must be the code causing the vertical-scroll bar on the left? I took out anything that might effect it out of the CSS, so is there anyway to make it go away?

Just in case here's the code for index/target0.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 <!--
 body {
background-image: url(../../2051__624x500_knitted-yarn-002051-forest-green.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat;
 }
-->
</style></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
<div id="controls">
<span class="textbg"></span>
<p><span class="textreg">
First |
Previous Picture |
<a href="target1.html">Next Picture</a> |
 <a href="target20.html">Last</a><br>
</span><hr size="1"></div>

<div id="image">
<img src="images/our_gorgeous_swimming_pool.jpg" width="240"  height="180"  title="swimmingpool.jpg (large)" border="0"><p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried deleting the thumbnails.html file altogether, but the scroll bar (frame?) is still there. So I want to ditch the vertical scroll bar and just have the "next/last" controls that are already there.

Comment: Could you link to the site in question, so that we can look at it via Firebug/Dragonfly, etc?

Comment: Sure - Here is a link: eugeneforestvillage.com/Gallery/Forest%20Village/… the vertical thumbnail "window" is what I'm wanting to get rid of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `scrolling` in the element `frame` controls whether the frame has a scrollbar.

You have it set to 'yes'. If you want this frame to have no scrollbars, set it to 'no'.

I took a look at your URL, made the change with Firebug and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks! But how would I get rid of that frame altogether? Every time I try and delete something it deletes everything .I just want that frame with the thumbnails gone...

Comment: @Jessica, I'm having problems understanding what you're after here. In that one sentence, you've expressed the desire to get rid of the frame altogether, but then you state that you just want that frame with the thumbnails gone.
A frame is just a webpage within a webpage. You control the contents of a frame by altering the webpage that it references.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow: hidden` in the CSS for the iframe as well as its contents should get rid of the scrollbar, but if the content is larger than the set width/height it will get cut off.